# Can i delegate django reporting to OpenERP

Tags: django, report, odoo

After search for a good solution for  enterprise reporting with django, i found OpenERP that i think is not just for reporting but has a WebKit report engine. Is OpenERP a good solution for django reporting or is to much for just reporting.
I try other reporting tools but any are good enough (django-report-builder,django-easy-report)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you would do this.  You would need some kind of ETL process to get the data into OpenERP but after that Django would need to make a call to OpenERP to ask it to generate the PDF and hand it back (or write it to disk so Django can get it back).  However, the report engine in OpenERP is just mako templates and wkhtmltopdf.  In Django you could use Django templates for the report to generate the HTML, write it to disk, then call wkhtmltopdf as it is just an excecutable to convert to PDF and then serve that back to the customer.

Comment: The problems with writing my own report using django templates are that the users need to create its own custom report without a programming approach